# Only tab between controls of my choice

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, tabs

I have a ASP.NET website where I have a login page. On this page I have 2 textboxes and a button. Now, when I open any browser, when I press the tab button it goes to my first textbox, second textbox and button. But after that it goes to any buttons a browser has. So for example, in IE it will go to the search bar, refresh button and home button before it gets back at textbox 1. Is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: there might be something in one of these answers that helps you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526909/how-to-disable-tab-key-globally-except-for-all-forms-in-a-page-with-javascript

Comment: I tried the solution that was accepted as a answer in the link that you provided me, worked until I reached my last control after that it does not return to my first control unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)` checking that `keyData == Keys.Tab`.

Then move to the desired control following the one which currently has the focus :

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tabindex` html attribute.  The number of that attribute should be the order that that element is in the tab cycle.

This is a plain HTML concept, although there is an ASP attribute that will map it to the HTML attribute, so you can use this for both HTML and ASP controls.